# Backing up source files managed by source control software: TortoiseSVN

Tags: vb.net, version-control, tortoisesvn

I am new to source control and I am confused with something I read on a webpage yesterday (I don't have the link).  I have followed these instructions: "create folder structure", then "Start Reprobrowser", then copy source files into trunk folder.  Please see the screen shot below:

[image]

However, when I navigate to the folder using Windows Explorer I do not see this folder structure.  I see this:

[image]

Therefore I am wandering: where are the files physically stored? The reason I ask is because I want to ensure that NetBackup (corporate backup tool) backs up the correct directories.

Answer (score 1):

To make sense of the repository structure you need to read all the documentation on SVN, but the preferred way to backup a SVN repository is through the command

```
svnadmin dump your_svn_repository_path > destination_filename_backup.svn
```

You could put this command in a scheduled task running sometime before your corporate tool execute the full backup of your data and include the `destination_filename_backup.svn` in your backup job

If you ever need to restore the backup (after recreating the repository) you could use the command

```
svnadmin load your_svn_repository_path < destination_filename_backup.svn
```

Comment: Thanks +1.  What is the point in running the command before the corporate backup tool runs?